# Creating a static table in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've been playing with iReport (older version 3.0.0) for a while and I can't seem to find a way to make just a static table, which seems silly and leads me to think that I'm just dense.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  The goal is to generate a report with a table with 2 columns: segment # and segment name.  For each report, there will always be 20 segments, so the end report would look something like the following:

```
| 1 | <segment name> |
| 2 | <segment name> |
...
| 20 | <segment name> |
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal way to create a table in Jasper is to use text-boxes (I know, this is not so *normal*, but Jasper is just dense)

To understand Jasper, you need to understand how the bands work.
The `Detail` band is used for each row of your data.

In the Detail band you should create two `Text Field`s, one with `$F{segment_id}` and one with `F${segment_name}` (Assuming your query use those fields).
When you run the report, this will become your table body.

To add a header to your table, use the `Column Header` band. Add `Static Text`s with 'ID' and 'Segment Name' - this will appear as a table header on each page.

Note that you should keep the text-boxes close together, taking the whole band hight, so it will look like a table and not just floating text-boxes.

(Note - this is the classic way to create tables in Jasper, but the new Jasper versions also contain a `Table` element designed specifically for tables)